Improve performance of onEdit simple trigger
I'm trying to get the middle initial from the middle name. Cell C12 in my script loads the middle name, while cell E12 loads the middle initial. To determine whether the text in cell C12 contains two words, I used the script chckWrd.includes(" ").
Example: Cell C12 is equals to "Dela Cruz", cell E12 must load the text "DC" upon entering.
Then I used 'chckWrd == ""' to determine whether cell C12 was empty. If it is empty, then cell E12 must likewise be empty.
The script runs fine, however it loads slowly. Is it possible to load it quickly or is there a shorter way for me to execute the script below?
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var cell = e.range;

  // STUDENT MIDDLE NAME
  if(cell.getA1Notation() === "C12" && ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "UserForm"){

      var myGoogleSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 
      var shUserForm    = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("UserForm"); //declare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet
      var chckWrd = shUserForm.getRange("C12").getValue();

      if (chckWrd == "") { // check if cell is empty

        shUserForm.getRange("E12").clear();
        shUserForm.getRange("E12").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize('12').setHorizontalAlignment("center");

      } else { // check if cell is not empty

        if (chckWrd.includes(" ")) { // check if cell includes space

        var wordArray = shUserForm.getRange("C12").getValue().split(" ");
        var first = wordArray[0].substring(0,1);
        var second = wordArray[1].substring(0,1);

        var middleInitial = first + second;

        Logger.log(middleInitial);

        shUserForm.getRange("E12").setValue(middleInitial);

        } else { // middle name has one word

          var wordArray = shUserForm.getRange("C12").getValue().substring(0,1);
          var first = wordArray[0].substring(0,1);
          Logger.log(first); // first word

          shUserForm.getRange("E12").setValue(first);

        }
      }
  }
}


In general, to improve the performance of a Google Apps Script, you should try to reduce the number of calls to Google Apps Script methods.
In the specific case of onEdit simple trigger, you might reduce the execution time by taking advantage of the edit event object properties.

source: Active Spreadsheet
range: Edited range
value: The edited value. Note this property is undefind when the edited cell is cleared.

Undocumented but known from a long time:

range.rowStart
range.columnStart
range.rowEnd
range.columnEnd

Examples:
Case 1
cell.getA1Notation() === "C12"

you might use
e.range.rowStart === 12 && e.range.columnStart === 3

Case 2
Instead of
var chckWrd = shUserForm.getRange("C12").getValue();

Consider using
e.value

There is no need to declare a variable; read the value.
Case 3
Instead of
chckWrd == ""

consider to use
e.value === undefined

Also, you might look for better alternatives for some methods, i.e., instead of
shUserForm.getRange("E12").clear();
shUserForm.getRange("E12").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize('12').setHorizontalAlignment("center");

consider to use
e.range.offset(0,2).clearContent();

The above option clears the cell content only, making it unnecessary to apply the cell background color, font settings and alignment.

I ran a pseudo benchmark (only one execution for each function). An accurate benchmark requires running hundreds of times, among other things, but this might be OK as a proof-of-concept.



Function name
Execution Time (console.time()/console.timeEnd()




original
1193 ms


proposal
2 ms



Note: The above times don't include the "transport time", the time it takes for Google servers to push the change to the user-on-keyboard web browser and the "repaint time", the time that it takes to the web browser to update the screen.
Code.gs
Change the index on const fn = name[1] to control which function runs.
function onEdit(e) {
  const name = ['original', 'proposal']
  const fn = name[1];
  console.time(fn);
  this[fn](e);
  console.timeEnd(fn);
}


Original.gs
Only the function name was changed for benchmarking purposes.
function original(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var cell = e.range;

  // STUDENT MIDDLE NAME
  if(cell.getA1Notation() === "C12" && ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "UserForm"){

      var myGoogleSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 
      var shUserForm    = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("UserForm"); //declare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet
      var chckWrd = shUserForm.getRange("C12").getValue();

      if (chckWrd == "") { // check if cell is empty

        shUserForm.getRange("E12").clear();
        shUserForm.getRange("E12").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize('12').setHorizontalAlignment("center");

      } else { // check if cell is not empty

        if (chckWrd.includes(" ")) { // check if cell includes space

        var wordArray = shUserForm.getRange("C12").getValue().split(" ");
        var first = wordArray[0].substring(0,1);
        var second = wordArray[1].substring(0,1);

        var middleInitial = first + second;

        Logger.log(middleInitial);

        shUserForm.getRange("E12").setValue(middleInitial);

        } else { // middle name has one word

          var wordArray = shUserForm.getRange("C12").getValue().substring(0,1);
          var first = wordArray[0].substring(0,1);
          Logger.log(first); // first word

          shUserForm.getRange("E12").setValue(first);

        }
      }
  }
}


Proposal.gs
function proposal(e) {

  // STUDENT MIDDLE NAME
  if(e.range.rowStart === 12 && e.range.columnStart === 12 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == "UserForm"){
      const target = e.range.offset(0,2);
      if (e.value ===  undefined) { // check if cell is empty

        target.clearContent();

      } else { // check if cell is not empty

        if (e.value.includes(" ")) { // check if cell includes space

        var wordArray = e.value.split(" ");
        var first = wordArray[0].substring(0,1);
        var second = wordArray[1].substring(0,1);

        var middleInitial = first + second;        

        target.setValue(middleInitial);

        } else { // middle name has one word

          var wordArray = e.value.substring(0,1);
          var first = wordArray[0].substring(0,1);

          target.setValue(first);

        }
      }
  }
}


Try it this way:
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "UserForm" && e.range.columnStart == 3 && e.range.rowStart == 12) {
    var sh1 = e.source.getSheetByName("UserForm");
    var chckWrd = sh1.getRange("C12").getValue();
    if (chckWrd == "") { 
      sh1.getRange("E12").clear();
      sh1.getRange("E12").setBackground('#FFFFFF').setFontFamily('Roboto').setFontSize('12').setHorizontalAlignment("center");
    } else { 
      if (chckWrd.includes(" ")) { 
        var wordArray = sh1.getRange("C12").getDisplayValue().split(" ");
        var first = wordArray[0].substring(0, 1);
        var second = wordArray[1].substring(0, 1);
        var middleInitial = first + second
        sh1.getRange("E12").setValue(middleInitial);
      } else {
        var wordArray = sh1.getRange("C12").getValue().substring(0, 1);
        var first = wordArray[0].substring(0, 1);
        sh1.getRange("E12").setValue(first);
      }
    }
  }
}


I edited e.range.columnStart == e to e.range.columnStart == 3 and it worked! It somehow lessen the loading time. Thank you!

I used more of the event object and called less functions
